# How to take a screenshot using python - selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

here is my simple code of python that I wrote to save the screenshot of a webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.save_screenshot("D\amanulla\test.png")
driver.quit()
```

Though, the program running without any errors, I do not see any screenshots saved on my machine. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `:` from `"D\amanulla\test.png"` and you need to escape the `\` as well, so effectively the line will be either:

```
"D:\\amanulla\\test.png"
```

or

```
"D:/amanulla/test.png"
```

Comment: you're welcome, please consider mark the answer as correct.

Comment: or just use the `os` builtin like this: `os.path.normpath("D:\amanulla\test.png")`

Comment: but adding `r` work `os.path.normpath(r"D:\amanulla\test.png")`

Answer (score 1):

> I do not see any screenshots saved on my machine

Look for a file named `Dmanulla est.png` in the *default Downloads location* for your browser... because that is what you are instructing WebDriver to do with the line:

> `driver.save_screenshot("D\amanulla\test.png")`

Explanation:

The string `"D\amanulla\test.png"` will be interpreted as `"Dmanulla    est.png"`.  This is because backslashes are escape sequences within Python strings.  Your directory separators will be interpreted as `\a` (bell) and `\t` (tab).

Also, the `:` separator is missing between the drive letter and the file path, so it is treating the entire string as a filename.  In the absence of a directory name, it should save to browser's default "Downloads" directory.

Solution:

`driver.save_screenshot(r"D:\amanulla\test.png")`

This uses a raw string so the backslashes are not interpreted as escape sequences, and it adds the missing `:` as the drive letter separator.